# How to add ssl security for all ports

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a domain and SSL certificate with GoDaddy.com  and hosting with DigitalOcean. My domain is working with SSL but SSL not providing security to different port numbers.

example: https://example.com is working but https://example.com:1234 is not working

What should I do now?  Is there any way to achieve this..?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming, but rather about network administration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certificate for `CN=example.com` (common name is example.com) can be used for any (or multiple) ports, but your HTTP(S) server software will need to be A.) listening on each port for SSL connections and B.) be prepared and configured to provide the certificate for each connection on those ports.

Do you have multiple applications running across those different ports? Each application HTTP server may need to be configured to listen (SSL mode) on that port **and** serve the SSL certificate for those connections.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: What software do you use to serve your website to users?

Comment: I'm using apache server

Comment: I'm no Apache expert, but the Basic Configuration section on this page looks like what you need in your apache configuration: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#page-header for each server (virtual host) that is running on a port.

Comment: it's not helping

Comment: Configuring Apache and your DigitalOcean server are a bit beyond the scope of the question asked here, so in order for someone to help further, you would need to ask a new question (preferable) or rewrite this question to ask something specific about your configuration, software, and server. The more details, the better.